# Selecting text from some elements inside a div and ignore other elements. HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, replace, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to build a web scraping tool for a news website. I'm having problems selecting the relevant text since the text is divided into multiple different elements. I'm using HTML Agility Pack and I have tried to select text ( //text() ) from the main div, but when I do this I get a lot of garbage text I don't want, like javascript code.
How can I select text from some nested elements and ignore other elements?

```html
<div class="texto_container paywall">
  Some text I want
  <a href="https://www.sabado.pt/sabermais/ana-gomes" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    Text I want
  </a> 
    sample of text I want
  <em>
    another text i want
  </em>
  <aside class="multimediaEmbed contentRight">
      A lot of nested elements here with some text I dont want
  </aside>
  <div class="inContent">
      A lot of nested elements here with some text I don't want
  </div>
  
  Back to the text I want!
  
  <twitter-widget class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" id="twitter-widget-0" >
    Don't want any of this text located in nested elements!
  </twitter-widget>
  
  <p>
    Final revelant text i want to collect!
  </p> 
  
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I tried to use XPath to exclude the tags I don't want, but I still get text nodes from those tags in the result.

```
var parse_me = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='texto_container paywall']//text()[not(parent::aside)][not(parent::div[@class='inContent'])][not(parent::twitter-widget)]");
```

I think this code doesn't work because on the tags I don't want to include the text parent nodes aren't the "main" tag, because it is inside of a lot of nested tags.

**EDIT**

After some thinking and some research I fixed the previous problem by using **ancestor::** instead of **parent::** and I got rid of some of the intended text.
But I still can't get rid of the **twitter-widget** text, because it always returns a null node even with the XPath copied from the Google Chrome inspect element tool.

```
var Twitter_Node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='twitter - widget - 0']");
```

This gets returned as null. How is this possible? XPath was copied from Chrome.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack uses XPath syntax - looking at your example html, you'll need to combine text from more than one selector. There are lots of [questions and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+agility+pack) on this site that can help you out.

Comment: Remove the spaces in your Xpath : `//*[@id='twitter-widget-0']`. Alternative : `//*[starts-with(./@id,"twitter")]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude the text from specific tags :

```
//body//text()[not(parent::aside)][not(parent::div[@class="inContent"])][not(parent::twitter-widget)]
```

You could use concat but it's more complicated since you have to know the number and the position of each tag in the "chain" :

```
concat(//body//div[@class="texto_container paywall"]/text()[1],//body//a[@href]/text(),//body//div[@class="texto_container paywall"]/text()[2],//body//em/text(),//body//div[@class="texto_container paywall"]/text()[5],//body//p/text())
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work, I added the code I used to the post.

Comment: The first solution works with the provided code. But yes, good call to use ancestor instead of parent since you have nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ScrapySharp` nuget which adds  in my sample below, (It's possible HtmlAgilityPack offers the same functionality built it, I am just used to ScrapySharp from years ago)

You can simply punctually extract all the texts you do NOT want, and then replace their occurrences in the main div text with an empty string, removing them from the final result.

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\Desktop\z.html"); //I created an html with your sample HTML set as the html body

    List<string> textsIWant = new List<string>();

    var textsIdoNotWant = new List<string>();
    //text I do not want
    var aside = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".multimediaEmbed.contentRight").FirstOrDefault();
    if (aside != null)
    {
        textsIdoNotWant.Add(aside.InnerText);
    }

    var inContent = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".inContent").FirstOrDefault();
    if (inContent != null)
    {
        textsIdoNotWant.Add(inContent.InnerText);
    }

    var twitterWidget = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("#twitter-widget-0").FirstOrDefault();
    if (twitterWidget != null)
    {
        textsIdoNotWant.Add(twitterWidget.InnerText);
    }

    var div = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".texto_container.paywall").FirstOrDefault();
    if (div != null)
    {
        var text = div.InnerText;
        foreach (var textIDoNotWant in textsIdoNotWant)
        {
            text = text.Replace(textIDoNotWant, string.Empty);
        }

        textsIWant.Add(text);
    }

    foreach (var text in textsIWant)
        Console.WriteLine(text);
```

[image]